# git rebase: Is it possible to lose work after rebasing a public commit?

Tags: git

I am currently learning to use the `git rebase` command. I already use it to squash commits together before pushing to the remote, but just now I noticed that I may have screwed up with that. Unfortunately I am not really sure about it and I also can't find any resources that specifically tell me what can happen, that's why I need your help. Here is what I did:

After squashing multiple commits together, I pushed them to remote. A few hours later, I rebased the branch with master, did some commits and squashed these into the commit I previously pushed, and pushed to remote.

I think this is exactly what one should not do since I rebased a commit that was already in public, but what is worst thing that can happen – can there work be lost?

By the way: I am pretty confident that no one else touched this branch or based work from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, you should not rebase a commit that has already been published. This is not really about losing work though but rather because it causes a mess for anyone who has been in touch with the repository in the meantime. And this usually means that they have to fix it manually by moving around their branch pointers and resetting stuff.

If you are confident that nobody else touched the branch—not even fetched it!—then there won’t be any consequences. But you might still want to warn people *if* you decide to push it.

That being said, just because you rebased it, this does not mean that you need to push that rebased commit. You could actually reset to the unrebased state. For example you can check the reflog using `git reflog` to get back to the original commit. Or you could fetch and then simply `git reset --soft origin/master` to get rid of all changes since the pushed commit (this only removes the history but keeps the changes in your working directory so you can make a new commit with that). That way you would restore a state that would be safe to push.

> can there work be lost?

Rebasing will obviously make you lose the original history you are rebasing. But unless you mess up merge conflicts, the *content* of the change should be identical and there shouldn’t be any loss.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Unfortunately, the rebased commit has been pushed. So I guess there isn't much I can do, but knowing that no work can be lost gives me some peace of mind back.